# Unable to clone a remote repository(On Premise) to a S3 Bucket using aws lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to make a connection from my On Premise git repository(Remote Url), which i am able to connect on my local using credentials, to AWS code build or code pipeline.

To achieve this, I have got solution statement from AWS side--

Currently CodeBuild only supports BitBucket repositories hosted on bitbucket.org , BitBucket Server (on-premise BitBucket) is not supported at this time. There is an existing feature request regarding supporting BitBucket Server in CodeBuild to which I've added your interest. I am unable to share an ETA as to when this feature may be released however you can keep an eye on the following sites for updates regarding this feature:

-- AWS CodeBuild Release History: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/history.html 
-- What's New: http://aws.amazon.com/new/
-- AWS Blogs: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/

There is a possible workaround by making a custom bridge between the Git repository and AWS, which can be done by creating a Lambda function that will clone the repository into a S3 bucket which can then be used as source in CodeBuild, you can read more about this here [1].

Hope that helps, if you have any questions please let me know, I'll be happy to help.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/git-to-s3-using-webhooks/

So i have implemented a lambda function like this:

```
public String handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) {

    final String REMOTE_URL = "https://username@stash.some.com/scm/something/dpautomation.git";

    CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("username", "password");
    try (Git result = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(REMOTE_URL).setDirectory(cretaeS3()).setCredentialsProvider(cp)
            .call()) {
        System.out.println("Having repository: " + result.getRepository().getDirectory());
    } catch (InvalidRemoteException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransportException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GitAPIException e) { // TODO Auto-generated
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "sucess";

}

public File cretaeS3() throws IOException {
  String bucketName = "selenium-lambda-java";
      String destinationKey ="screenshots_on_failure/testdata1";
      String filename="\"+temp";
      AmazonS3 s3Client =
      AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").withCredentials(new
      ProfileCredentialsProvider()).build();
      File src = new File(filename);
      s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, destinationKey, src));
     return src;
}
```

In the above code, as i have to copy Remote url repo files to directly to s3 bucket, so i used jgit.api.Git where when i tried to clone remote repo, i need to give some path in File format into setDirectory parameter while should ideally a bucket path so i tried the above code. i am getting below error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to calculate MD5 hash: \"+temp (No such file or directory)",
  "errorType": "com.amazonaws.SdkClientException",
"stackTrace": [   


"com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getInputStream(AmazonS3Client.java:1852)", "com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1770)",    "com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1749)",    "com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.cretaeS3(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:79)",  "com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:52)",    "com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:1)"  ],  "cause": {    "errorMessage": "\"+temp (No such file or directory)",
"errorType": "java.io.FileNotFoundException",
"stackTrace": [
  "java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)",
  "java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)",
  "java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)",
  "com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.computeMD5Hash(Md5Utils.java:97)",
  "com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(Md5Utils.java:104)",
  "com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getInputStream(AmazonS3Client.java:1848)",
  "com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1770)",
  "com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1749)",
  "com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.cretaeS3(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:79)",
  "com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:52)",
  "com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:1)"
]
```

}
}

I am stuck from last 5 days please some body help me on this.